# Add class and attribute with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry for my english..

I understand that it was done with addClass and removeClass but how to write terms do not understand
I need to do so if the screen resolution is less than 768 pixels then add the attributes `id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"` and the class `"dropdown-menu"` to the `ul` with class `small` and remove class from `li` `parent` class and remove the ul with class `nav-child`

**UPD**

I have this:

```
<li class="item-104 deeper parent">
  <span class="nav-header ">About</span>
  <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
   <li class="item-113"><a href="/o-ministerstve/novosti">News</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

i want do this, when window screen less than 768px:

```
<li class="item-104 deeper">
      <span class="nav-header " id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About</span>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu unstyled small">
       <li class="item-113"><a href="/o-ministerstve/novosti">News</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

I want to remove the classes nav-child and parent and add to span attributes

can someone come in handy:

```
$(function () {
    var window_width = 750; // or $(window).width();

    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      $('.small').addClass('dropdown-menu');
      $('.deeper').removeClass('parent');
      $('.small').removeClass('nav-child');
      $('.deeper .nav-header').attr({id: 'dLabel', type: 'button', 'data-toggle':'dropdown', 'aria-haspopup':'true', 'aria-expanded': 'false'});
    } else {
      $('.small').removeClass('dropdown-menu');
      $('.deeper').addClass('parent');
      $('.small').addClass('nav-child');
      $('.deeper .nav-header').attr({id: '', type: '', 'data-toggle':'', 'aria-haspopup':'', 'aria-expanded': ''});
    }
});
```

Comment: I've added a solution, but unfortunately i do not understand your condition, when attributes should be romved.

Comment: I've added a snippet to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For adding attributes and classes you could use:

```
$('ul.small').attr({id: 'dLabel', type: 'button', data-toggle:'dropdown', aria-haspopup:'true', aria-expanded: 'false'});
$('ul.small').addClass('dropdown-menu');
```

Removing is simpler, because then you set the attribute to an empty string:

```
$('ul.small').attr({id: '', type: '', data-toggle:'', aria-haspopup:'', aria-expanded: ''});
```

Current size of your windows can be get with:

```
$( window ).width()
```

Or do you want this attributes to be given on resize events? Then just try:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  if ($( window ).width() < 768){
    $('ul.small').addClass('firstClass').addClass('secondClass');
    $('ul.small').attr({id: 'dLabel', type: 'button', data-toggle:'dropdown', aria-haspopup:'true', aria-expanded: 'false'});
  } else {
   $('ul.small').removeClass('firstClass').removeClass('secondClass');
    $('ul.small').attr({id: '', type: '', data-toggle:'', aria-haspopup:'', aria-expanded: ''});
  }
}
```

After author has edited his question:

```js
var window_width = 750; // or $(window).width();

if ($(window).width() < 768) {
  $('#deeper').removeClass('parent');
  $('#deeper .nav-header').attr({id: 'dLabel', type: 'button', 'data-toggle':'dropdown', 'aria-haspopup':'true', 'aria-expanded': 'false'});
} else {
  $('#deeper').addClass('parent');
  $('#deeper .nav-header').attr({id: '', type: '', 'data-toggle':'', 'aria-haspopup':'', 'aria-expanded': ''});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="item-104 deeper parent">
  <span class="nav-header ">About</span>
  <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
   <li class="item-113"><a href="/o-ministerstve/novosti">News</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: $( window ).resize(function() {
  if ($( window ).width() > 768){
    $('ul').addClass('ferstClass secondClass');
  } else {
    // remove attr
    $('li').removeClass('parent');
  }
}
This is don't work :(

Comment: Please post your code as edit above! You have to add every class individual!

Comment: Thank you maaan )))) I love you ;D

Answer (score 2):

You are using addClass and removeClass, means you have jQuery included. Use this:

```
if($(window ).width() < 768){       // Returns width of browser viewport
     // addClass
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if ($(window).width() < 768) {

        $("ul").attr({id:"dLabel",type:"button",data-toggle:"dropdown",aria-haspopup:"true",aria-expanded="false"});


        $("ul").addClass("dropdown-menu");

        //and rest code..........

    }

    else {

        // go back Default...
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative: draw both types and hide one or other using CSS.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  #first { display: block; }
  #second { display: none; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #first { display: none; }
  #second { display: block; }
}
```

much easier to design and debug in my opinion